# alert box automatic disappear

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I'm using Bootstrap and want to realize the following:
having a kind of an alert box which disappears after a short period of time automatically. I have something special in my Imagination which I saw often but can't find at the moment. I think the standard bootstrap alert (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts and http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) is not the right thing, is it? Because I want something to just "appear on top of something", so not as content of the page, if you know what I mean.

So it should just show a short "success information" when entering the page, and then it should disappear again. Or do I missunderstand Bootstrap alert wrong and it's exactly what I'm searching for? If yes, how do I use it? Where do I have to put that "div"?

Comment: I use toastr for something like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's also possible with alerts. Just add a timeout for the closing and add `position: fixed` style to have the alert in front of your content.

The following demo should give you an idea how you could use it.

The same code is also at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/bnvj2w7u/).

```js
$().alert();

setTimeout(function(){$('.alert').alert('close')}, 3000);
```

```css
.alert {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
     <h4>Oh snap! You got an error!</h4>

    <p>Change this and that and try again. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
</div>

<div><h1>Normal content</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This is exactly what I was looking for. I have just a little issue. When I dont use css to fix the position, the alert takes the full width of the screen, when I add position:fixed; top:0; than it's just a little box in the top left corner, even with a "newline" in it, so 2 lines for 2 words in my case. Do you know why?

Comment: Not sure why this happens but you can fix it with adding `width: 100%;` to the alert class.

Comment: This works again, but is connected with the next issue.... The alert is in the background... so when I e.g. write `top:40px` then the content of the page is in front of the alert, so you can't see it..

Comment: I can't see this issue in the fiddle. Please post the link to a fiddle with that issue.

Comment: I was able to fix it know, just setting `z-index` to a high value. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alert box, you can consider something like bootstrap modal. Focus on the usage of the html and js

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Here is a simple code block that can open modal on click, and auto dismiss modal after 2 seconds.

Html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  window.setTimeout(closeModal, 2000)
});

function closeModal(){
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByrZwv